# tricky sql Ordering

Tags: sql, select, oracle11g, sql-order-by

i have a table on oracle 11g that looks like this

```
col_1 |   col_2   |  col_3 |
1     | 111222001 |   A
2     | 111222001 |   B
3     | 111222002 |   A
4     | 111222002 |   B
5     | 111555001 |   B
6     | 111555003 |   A
7     | 111555003 |   B
```

i want to order it, to get this

```
col_1 |   col_2   |  col_3 |
2     | 111222001 |   B
4     | 111222002 |   B
1     | 111222001 |   A
3     | 111222002 |   A
5     | 111555001 |   B
7     | 111555003 |   B
6     | 111555003 |   A
```

Logic behind it :

notice how col_2 values are values of three triplets 111-222-333.

I want to order col_2 according to the the third triplet 111-222-"333" and get  only the entries that have col_3 = 'B' at first, then get those that have col_3 = 'A' .
when the second triplet (changes / goes up) 111-"222"-333 we redo what was described before.

Thanks in advance, i fureg out a way to do it, but it's really ugly, if someone can figure out a way to do it beautifully

Comment: So... what's the problem?  Did you try adding those `ORDER BY` conditions to the query...?

Comment: yes but i don't get the result i want

Comment: Hint:  `order by substr(col_2, 7, 9), substr(col_2, 4, 6), col3 desc`.  I will note that the order you show in the data does not conform to the rules you have described.

Comment: i deleted the part that  was confusing, thanks for the fast replies, hope someone can give lead me to the right sql code

Comment: I don't understand the way you want to sort this?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HI i don't know why i didn't see it, but it was quite simple, sorry for troubling you

select col_1, col_2, col_3 from table_name
order by substr(col_2,3,8), col_3, substr(col_2,9,11);

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * 
from table
order by col_3 desc, col2, col1;
```

Comment: hello, thanks for the response but it doesn't give the result i want

Comment: Logically it should , as I tested this ordering in my access database